# Best a very overloaded query mongodb - Nodejs; aggregate, group, porject and lookup

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, performance

its my first question in this forum. (I am a Spanish speaker, sorry for my basic English)

I have 3 collections: images, artists and exhibitions.

1. Images has: filename (unique), path and _id and etc.
2. Artists has: name, url (unique) and description and etc
3. Exhibitions has: name, url (unique), year, abstract, aristUrl (artist.url) imageCover (image.fieldname) and etc.

Whit my query this is my summary result:

```
[
        _id: null,
        documents: [{...}, {...}],
        totalExhibitions: 2
]
```

Full result

```
[
    {
        "_id": null,
        "documents": [
            {
                "_id": "5e84d6599891212db0a6dc7e",
                "url": "chile",
                "imageCover": [
                    {
                        "path": "http://localhost:2616/uploads/images/1585763637647.jpg"
                    }
                ],
                "name": "Almacén Verdad y Justicia",
                "year": 2010,
                "releaseDate": "2010-08-30T00:00:00.000Z",
                "artist": [
                    {
                        "name": "Bernardo de Castro Saavedra",
                        "url": "bernardo-castro-saavedra"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "_id": "5e84e0575a3f201aac2df1c2",
                "url": "sin-cera",
                "imageCover": [
                    {
                        "path": "http://localhost:2616/uploads/images/1585766437587.jpg"
                    }
                ],
                "name": "Sin cera",
                "year": 2020,
                "releaseDate": "2020-01-31T00:00:00.000Z",
                "artist": [
                    {
                        "name": "Gonzalo Tapia",
                        "url": "gonzalo-tapia"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "totalExhibitions": 2
    }
]
```

This is my code

```
getByLastYear(){
        const documents = this.mongoDB.aggregate([
            {
                $addFields: {
                    "artistObjectId": { $toObjectId: "$artistId" }
                }
            },{
                $lookup: {
                    from: 'artists',
                    localField: 'artistObjectId',
                    foreignField: "_id",
                    as: "artist"
                },
            },{
                $lookup: {
                    from: 'images',
                    localField: 'imageCover',
                    foreignField: "filename",
                    as: "imageCover"
                },
            },{
                $project: {
                    name: 1,
                    year: 1,
                    url: 1,
                    releaseDate: 1,
                    artist: {
                        name: 1,
                        url: 1
                    },
                    imageCover: {
                        path: 1,
                        alt: 1,
                    }

                }
            }, {
                $group: {
                    _id: null,
                    documents: {
                        $push: "$$ROOT"
                    },
                    totalExhibitions: {
                        $sum: 1
                    }

                }
            }

        ]);
        return documents || [];
    };
```

that is the best form to get my result?
is there any better?

Thank you for your comments and opinions.<3

Comment: Hi there! You mention that you have `artistUrl` in your Exhibition, but you are using `artistId` in your code (I am assuming that `this.mongoDB` is for the Exhibition collection). Which one is it? Consider storing `artistId` in you Exhibition as an actual ObjectId, so that you don't have to convert it in your `$addFields`. If this aggregate is going to return a big array of `documents`, it might be worth to consider using a cursor to iterate through them instead and remove the `$group` stage.

Comment: Hi!, thanks for your reply, yes this.mongoDB correspond to the native library and I'm sorry, I was wrong, I used artistId, not artistUrl. I hadn't thought about what you mention; It is better to save the id data as objectid, not as string. I understand the $group, but how can I save the total number of exhibitions in another field like my result?

Comment: A separate query to count the Exhibition collection should do the trick. Note that this is only an issue if your are going to get a huge overall object, otherwise, the `$group` should not be an issue. (It is just a bit of a red flag when you grouping by nothing and pushing `$$ROOT` or in another way combine all documents of a collection into a single object).

Comment: Also, see the answer by @georgbc, it gives some further good suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that:

- you're starting from the exhibitions collection;
- the "_id" fields have an ObjectId format;
- there's only 1 artist and 1 cover image for each exhibition...

I'd skip the first step and add in $unwind stages to have the artist and the cover image as a subdocument instead of an array.
The reason for that is that it will make it easier to reference the result.

This should be able to run in your Mongo shell:

```
db.exhibitions.aggregate([
{ $lookup: {
    from: 'artists',
    localField: "artistId",
    foreignField: "_id",
    as: "artist"
}},
{ $unwind: {
    path: "$artist",
    preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
}},
{ $lookup: {
    from: 'images',
    localField: 'imageCover',
    foreignField: "filename",
    as: "imageCover"
}},
{ $unwind: {
    path: "$imageCover",
    preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
}},
{ $project: {
    name: 1,
    year: 1,
    url: 1,
    releaseDate: 1,
    artist: {
      name: "$artist.name",
      url: "$artist.url"
    },
    imageCover: {
      path: "$imageCover.path",
      alt: "$imageCover.alt",
    }
}},
{ $group: {
    _id: null,
    documents: {
      $push: "$$ROOT"
    },
    totalExhibitions: {
      $sum: 1
    }
}}
]);
```

In the "$project" stage, for artist and imageCover, you would need to specify the full path to build the reduced subdocument.

Hope that answered your question...